# How to get ios Bundle ID that other actions use

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

My Fastlane is configured and working great. Match is setup and working great. Everything automatically detects the project and the bundle ID and is working great...

But I need to manually set profile_path in the following:

> automatic_code_signing(
>         use_automatic_signing: false,
>         team_id: "ZZZZ",
>         code_sign_identity: "iPhone Developer",
>         profile_name: ENV['sigh_com.blah.blah_development_profile-name']
>        )

That requires knowing the bundle ID to pass into environment variable. All actions seems to know the bundle ID, but I can't get it anywhere. I don't want to manually hardcode the ID.

If I don't do the above step, even with match setup, the build fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like using `CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier)` should be enough to get the app identifier, assuming you have it defined as part of your `Appfile` or similar.